# Combinatorics: counting groups of contiguous "on" switches

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set of $N$ switches organized side-by-side in a linear fashion.
For example, with $N=5$, it might look like this:

```
1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 1
```

I am interested in counting the groups of contiguous switches in the "on" position after $m$ randomly-selected switches are turned off.

### Flipping one switch

If one of the switches is selected at random and turned off, the possible outcomes are (sets at the end show the groups of contiguous "on" switches):

```
0 -- 1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 1 <-- {4}
1 -- 0 -- 1 -- 1 -- 1 <-- {1, 3}
1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 1 -- 1 <-- {2, 2}
1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 1 <-- {3, 1} which is the same as {1, 3} for my purposes
1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 0 <-- {4}
```

There are two cases with $\{4\}$, two with $\{1,3\}$ and one with $\{2,2\}$. The set of potential outcomes and number of occurrences of each are
$$
S(N=5,m=1) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\{4\}& 2 \\
\{3,1\}& 2 \\
\{2,2\}& 1 \\
\end{array}\right.$$
In particular, I am interested in knowing the probability of the different sizes of groups, i.e.:
$$
p(N=5,m=1) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
4 & 2 \\
3 & 2 \\
2 & 2 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Even though there is only one outcome with $2$ in it, because that outcome has it twice, it is just as likely as the other numbers. For $m=1$, all values between $1$ and $N-1$ have 2 potential ways to come to that value.

### Flipping the second switch

For each outcome ($\{4\}$, $\{3,1\}$, $\{2, 2\}$) we can again work out the potential outcomes for $m=2$.

For $\{4\}$:

```
1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 0 <--- {3}
1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 1 -- 0 <--- {2,1}
1 -- 0 -- 1 -- 1 -- 0 <--- {2,1}
0 -- 1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 0 <--- {3}
```

For $\{3,1\}$:

```
1 -- 1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 0 <--- {3}
1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 0 -- 1 <--- {2,1}
1 -- 0 -- 1 -- 0 -- 1 <--- {1,1,1}
0 -- 1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 1 <--- {2,1}
```

For $\{2,2\}$:

```
1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 1 -- 0 <--- {2,1}
1 -- 1 -- 0 -- 0 -- 1 <--- {2,1}
1 -- 0 -- 0 -- 1 -- 1 <--- {2,1}
0 -- 1 -- 0 -- 1 -- 1 <--- {2,1}
```

And so:
$$
p(N=5,m=2) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
3 & 6 \\ 
2 & 12 \\
1 & 18 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

### More switches

Working through the problem manually, we can find the following breakdown for the number of contiguous switches in the "on" position.

| flips | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 18 | 12 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 72 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 120 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I would like to generate this table for arbitrary $N$. I can solve it recursively with programming, but am wondering if there is a combinatorial way demonstrate it.

**Update:**

As suggested by @WW1, we can divide the table above by $(m+1)!$ to see the pattern (expanded below to $N=10$).

| flips | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 28 | 21 | 15 | 10 | 6 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 56 | 35 | 20 | 10 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 70 | 35 | 15 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 56 | 21 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 28 | 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**Update 2**:

Looking at the chart above that has been normalized by $(m+1)!$, the normalized number of cases with $k$ contiguous after $m$ switches (let's denote this $n_{k,m}$) can be determined as
$n_{k,m} = n_{k+1,m} + n_{k+1,m-1}$, so I can iteratively build the table of arbitrary size quite quickly. However, I am still hoping to find a mathematical explanation/proof to support the observation.

Comment: You seem to be keeping track of the order in which the switches are turned off - you could simplify your table a little by not doing that ( divide each row by $m!$. ) This won't have any impact on the probabilities you seek.

Comment: You should observe also that you have a Pascal triangle.

Comment: Thanks @BillyJoe! I was too busy looking *horizontally* (constant $m$) to think to look *vertically* (at constant $k$). Now I see my observation in update 2 is describing a Pascal triangle.